# JWT token does not expires in Node Js

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have developed the JWT token and everything is working fine. Like Generating and Verification the token. But the issue is that i have added the expire time but when i use the old tokens it redirect me to my web.

```
jwt.sign(user, process.env.privateKey, { expiresIn: '1h' })
```

Can anyone tell me what to do?

I have searched for the solution some people said to clear out the cookies also if someone want to suggest me clear cookies then tell me how to clear them. A proper way to clear.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a middleware to verify the JWT. This will check that the JWT was signed by you and (more important to the question) if it expired.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback

Comment: Can you elaborate how specifically expire the token?

Comment: If you are using cookies you can just Unset the cookie. If you don't use cookies you can't (you will have to drop the requests)

Answer (score 0):

**In Middleware**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const HttpResponse = require('../models/http-response');


require('custom-env').env(process.env.NODE_ENV);
const secret_key=process.env.secret_key;

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
     return next();
     }
  try {
     const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]; // Authorization: 'Bearer 
      TOKEN'
      if (!token) {
        throw new Error('Authentication failed!');
        }
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, secret_key);
      req.userData = { userId: decodedToken.userId };
      next(); 
      } catch (err) {
         const error = new HttpResponse('Authentication failed!', 403);
         return res.json({ response: error });
         }
      };
```

Comment: i did not find the answer of my question, i want to know how expireIn option of jwt work in code

Comment: try this           token=jwt.sign({user}, process.env.privateKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });

Comment: Please read the question first i have use this but still it is accessible after 1 hour

Comment: in my case, its working, it get expires after 1 hr.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are overriding the default algorithm in the sign parameter. In that case, pass `expiresIn` as another key rather different object.

Should be:

> jwt.sign(data, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS512', expiresIn: expiry })

But not:

> jwt.sign(data, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS512'}, { expiresIn: expire })

which works pretty good